# Early voting data for Ohio House elections 2021?

Tags: united-states, election, data-sources, ohio

In Ohio there are two general elections for the House, in the 11th and 15th district. Both are to different degrees considered safe seats.

Early voting started last Tuesday. I want to see the number of votes cast in total for each House general election so far. Is this information publicly available or do we have to wait for Election Night to get info like this?

Comment: Is this for the Ohio House or the US House?

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- US; see https://ballotpedia.org/Special_elections_to_the_117th_United_States_Congress_(2021-2022)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This data is available at the county level, if you don't mind doing a bit of collation work:

**11th District**

- [Cuyahoga County Board of Elections](https://boe.cuyahogacounty.gov/) publishes both a 'Vote-by-Mail Daily Update' and an 'Early In-Person Daily Update'.
- Summit County Board of Elections has an [absentee voter dashboard](https://www.summitcountyboe.gov/boe-reports/absentee-reports/).

**15th District**

- Union County uses the [same dashboard style](https://lookup.boe.ohio.gov/vtrapp/union/avreport.aspx) as Summit County's
- Madison County uses [the same dashboard](https://lookup.boe.ohio.gov/vtrapp/madison/avreport.aspx).
- Franklin County Board of Elections [publishes a report](https://vote.franklincountyohio.gov/Voters/Absentee-Voting/District-Counts) of absentee ballots requested, mailed, and returned, and provides a [tool to export data](https://vote.franklincountyohio.gov/Maps-Data/Absentee-Voter-Labels) on
  early voting.

Bear in mind when interpreting the data that where a voter's party is reported, this is different to how many other states report party affiliation. Party is only reported if a voter cast a ballot in a party's primary in the current year, or the last two calendar years (See [Ohio Rev. Code 3513.19(3)](https://law.justia.com/codes/ohio/2006/orc/jd_3513191-bd5d.html)). As Democrats had more incentive to vote in their party's presidential primary in 2020 compared to Republicans - due to President Trump's lack of primary challengers - drawing conclusions based on this reported affiliation is likely to be flawed.